# Detecting if the wifi is enabled in swift

Tags: asynchronous, swift, wifi

In my app i have some NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest but because of that if the user has wifi disabled the app crashes.

Is there a way to detect if the wifi is disabled so i can do something like that:

```
if(wifi is enabled)
{
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Found the answer in this blog post](http://idictate.us/questions/25623272/working-with-c-structs-in-swift):

Step 1:

Add "SystemConfiguration" framework to your project

Step 2:

Add this function to your project:

```
func isConnectionAvailble()->Bool{

    var rechability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.apple.com").takeRetainedValue()

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0

    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(rechability, &flags) == 0
    {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: I have added the SystemConfiguration framework but it says that the Reachablity and NetworkStatus type are undeclared

Comment: Yeah, I see that problem too.  I've done some research and have reworked my answer.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello guys, how is that I add the framework then I paste the function in my view but everything generates problems? All the problem are the same: "use of underclared type 'SC....' thanks for helping me :))

Comment: this sounds like a separate problem and you should enter in a separate question for this @ernestocattaneo... I am thinking something inside your .swift file needs to be adjusted (e.g. "`#import SystemConfiguration`")

Comment: You wouldn't import that into your swift file though, wouldn't you wanna import that into the bridging header as `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>`?

Comment: Is this for detecting WiFi only? Or does it return true if any sort of data connection is available (LTE, 3G).

Comment: [`SCNetworkReachabilityFlags`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) includes a `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN` flag where you know if the site is reachable through a cellular connection.  If that flag is not set, then I'd say it's safe to assume it's a WiFi connection.  And if you only want WiFi connections and the flag for `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN` is set to true, return false from my `isConnectionAvailable` function up there.

Answer (score 4):

And now for a Swift 2.0:

```
func isConnectionAvailble()->Bool{

    let rechability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.apple.com")

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()

    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(rechability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```