# not able detect wifi is on or off on iPad 2 model only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm using below code snippet to detect if wifi is enabled or not.
This code works fine on iPad Air or

```
(BOOL) isWiFiEnabled {

    NSCountedSet * cset = [NSCountedSet new];

    struct ifaddrs *interfaces;

    if( ! getifaddrs(&interfaces) ) {
        for( struct ifaddrs *interface = interfaces; interface; interface = interface->ifa_next) {
            if ( (interface->ifa_flags & IFF_UP) == IFF_UP ) {
                [cset addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:interface->ifa_name]];
            }
        }
    }

    return [cset countForObject:@"awdl0"] > 1 ? YES : NO;
}
```

For iPad 2 generation model this code does not work i.e. it returns 0.
Please help me on this i.e. any other way to detect wifi on or off on this model.

This issue is specific to iPad 2 model only and i have already mentioned it works fine for iPad Air and other models.

Comment: You can use Apple's `Reachability` class and bridge into swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting if the wifi is enabled in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086488/detecting-if-the-wifi-is-enabled-in-swift)

Comment: this issue is specific to model as mentioned above

Comment: @Manisha The code in the duplicate question linked by mxmlc is different from what you're using, and doesn't hard-code the interface name `awdl0`. It should work on all models.

Comment: @ duskwuff  - i debugged the code and for iPad2 it returns false even though interface is awdl0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try interface "**en1**" instead of "**awdl0**" for the older iPad devices in the Reachability class. You can add if condition to check for "en1" interface along with "awdl0" interface.

AFAIK "**awdl0**" interface does not work on iPhone 4/4s but not sure about iPad 2.